# Language confusion using Open Multilingual Wordnet with NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet, open-multilingual-wordnet

I'm trying to understand NLTK's Wordnet module. Even downloading the omw-1.4 module, when I request the synsets of a word in Portuguese it returns terms in English.
When I ask for the languages loaded in the module, only 'eng' appears, but I understand that others should appear, since I loaded Open Multilingual Wordnet (omw-1.4).
The same does not happen when I request synonyms. The synonyms all appear in Portuguese.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('wordnet')
nltk.download('omw-1.4')

    [nltk_data] Downloading package wordnet to /root/nltk_data...
    [nltk_data]   Package wordnet is already up-to-date!
    [nltk_data] Downloading package omw-1.4 to /root/nltk_data...
    [nltk_data]   Package omw-1.4 is already up-to-date!
    True

from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wnet
sorted(wnet.langs())
    ['eng']

wnet.synsets("casa", lang='por')
[Synset('apartment.n.01'),
 Synset('building.n.01'),
 Synset('chalet.n.01'),
 Synset('cringle.n.01'),
 Synset('detached_house.n.01'),
 Synset('dwelling.n.01'),
 Synset('house.n.01'),
 Synset('house.n.12'),
 Synset('housing.n.01'),
 Synset('theater.n.01'),
 Synset('house.n.06'),
 Synset('manufacturer.n.01'),
 Synset('family.n.01'),
 Synset('residence.n.01'),
 Synset('domicile.n.01'),
 Synset('home.n.01'),
 Synset('home.n.06'),
 Synset('home.n.07')]

wnet.synonyms("casa",lang='por')

  #output:      
    [['apartamento', 'aposentos'],
         ['edifício', 'edifícios', 'prédio'],
         ['chalé'],
         ['ilhó'],
         [],
         ['aposento',
          'domicílio',
          'habitação',
          'lar',
          'morada',
          'moradia',
          'residência'],
         ['Habitações',
          'edifícios_residenciais',
          'firma',
          'habitação',
          'teatro',
          'vivenda'],
         [],
         ['abrigo', 'abrigos', 'alojamentos'],
         ['teatro'],
         [],
         ['fabricante'],
         ['agregado_familiar',
          'classe',
          'família',
          'linhagem',
          'pessoa_da_família_que_mora_na_mesma_casa'],
         ['domicílio', 'residência'],
         ['domicílio'],
         ['Lar', 'lar'],
         ['lar'],
         ['lar']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Synset('apartment.n.01'),` is the name of a graph node; it has been named after an English word, but you have to do an extra step to get text in English (or any language).

So to get the human language text use `lemma_names()`, like this:

```
wnet.synset('apartment.n.01').lemma_names('por')
```

Ref: https://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html

Comment: After studying a little more and with the help of your answer I understood that the nodes will always be in English, but other attributes of the synset will be invoked in the language you want.
Before that I had not understood synsets as 'entities' or objects but rather as a common attribute....

But I also noticed a detail in the code/library. When I ask for sorted(wn.langs()) it returns [eng] even though I loaded the own-1.4.
After some time or running another code in the sequence, I call sorted(wn.langs()) again and it returns the complete list!

Comment: Yes, in the nltk.org page it says "These languages are not loaded by default, but only lazily, when needed.". So the return of `wn.langs()` changes after you've used a language - a bit counter-intuitive.